# copying files from remote desktop using php

Tags: php, remote-access

I am learning php and want to know is there any possibility by which we can copy files from remote desktop to server or get remote access to files on the host machine. however as far as i know php is a used for server side scripting.

Comment: By witch way you want to copy files on your webserver ? Ssh, ftp SMB ... ?

Comment: If the remote desktop user uploads them

Comment: without any permission i know this is wrong but its just for study purpose that if a user runs a php application the code search for a particular file with particular extension and copy it to server any possibility?

Comment: @user2641848 : Use php ftp functions

Comment: and if not php which language is suitable for it.?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can copy files from remote server if you have previlliages/rights [here is link](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.copy.php#83955)

```
<?php
if(!@copy('http://someserver.com/somefile.zip','./somefile.zip'))
{
    $errors= error_get_last();
    echo "COPY ERROR: ".$errors['type'];
    echo "<br />\n".$errors['message'];
} else {
    echo "File copied from remote!";
}
?>
```